# Insert a new column in between to an existing excel file using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file which have 2 columns. I want to add a new column in between existing first and second using java program.
I am trying to use Apache POI for this purpose. I went through the api docs and some of the related stack over flow questions but I could find examples which only delete/update the cells(not inserting an entire column).

Can any one share useful pointer to this? The only solution which I can think as if now is create a new sheet with 3 columns copy 1st column and 3rd column value from old

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution https://github.com/bit-twit/poi-shift-column/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bittwit/poi/ExcelOpener.java. It's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sheet.shiftColumns(startColumn, endColumn, n)`
Shifts columns between startColumn and endColumn, n number of columns. If you use a negative number, it will shift columns left. Code ensures that columns don't wrap around.

1. startColumn – the column to start shifting
2. endColumn – the column to end shifting
3. n – the number of columns to shift

Comment: `shiftColumns(...)` not found in the current version.